# MultiObjective problems using gurobi solver - which method is used?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, gurobi, julia-jump

I'm coding a mathematical model in Julia, using the packages JuMP and Gurobi.

So, first I create my model and set some parameters, as below:

```
model = Model(Gurobi.Optimizer)

set_optimizer_attribute(model, "TimeLimit", 600)

set_optimizer_attribute(model, "Presolve", 0)
```

After, I define the constraints and the objectives. The first objective (obj1) is to maximize, while the second objective (obj2) is to minimize. This way, I define the objective and try to solve the model, as below:

```
@objective(model, Min, [-eff_expr, instruments_expr])

optimize!(model)

status = termination_status(model)

println("STATUS: ", status, " ---------------------------")

print(solution_summary(model))
```

After that, a set of solutions is returned. My question is: what is the method used by Gurobi to solve this problem? weighted-sum?

Thank you very much.

I'm trying to know the method used by Gurobi to solve a biobjective problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify `weighted sum` or `lexicographic`. Gurobi calls this `blended` and `hierarchical`. This is actually documented. See: https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/10.0/refman/working_with_multiple_obje.html

Default is weighted sum with weights equal to 1.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. 
Can you help with more doubts? 

   i) If the weight is 1 for each objective, my objective will be **minimize instruments_expr - eff_expr**?

   ii) Considering a weighted sum approach with the weights as 1 for each objective, the set of solutions that I found after running the problem is a partial Pareto frontier? This explains why my plot has only extreme solutions.

   ii) Is there a simple way to vary the weights, ensuring that w1 + w2 == 1 for all combinations? (I did think of a simple code with fors, but there could be other ways to do this).

Comment: A weighted sum approach will deliver a point that is Pareto optimal, but it may not find all Pareto optimal points. I usually model this myself. I am not sure if what the solver provides here is much better than just forming a weighted sum yourself.

Comment: I understood Erwin, thank you for your support. I'm going to try by the weighted sum.

Answer (score 0):

The `MultiObjectiveAlgorithms.jl` package implements a number of different algorithms that can find you the frontier. Use, for example:

```
using JuMP
import Gurobi
import MultiObjectiveAlgorithms as MOA
model = Model(() -> MOA.Optimizer(Gurobi.Optimizer))
set_attribute(model, MOA.Algorithm(), MOA.Dichotomy())
# ... same model as before ...
```

See also:

- https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/packages/MultiObjectiveAlgorithms/
- https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/tutorials/linear/multi_objective_examples/
- https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/tutorials/linear/multi_objective_knapsack/

Comment: Hi Oscar, thank you so much for the support. 
My initial aim was to use MOA.EpsilonConstraint() algorithm to find the Pareto frontier, but I got the following error: In `MathOptInterface.ScalarAffineFunction{Float64}`-in-`MathOptInterface.LessThan{Float64}` constraint: Constant -7.028337531486145 of the function is not zero. The function constant should be moved to the set. You can use `MOI.Utilities.normalize_and_add_constraint` which does this automatically. This error is returned after the algorithm finds 6 solutions.

Comment: Now, I did try by MOA.Dichotomy(), but I got other error: MathOptInterface.SetAttributeNotAllowed{MathOptInterface.TimeLimitSec}: Setting attribute MathOptInterface.TimeLimitSec() cannot be performed. You may want to use a `CachingOptimizer` in `AUTOMATIC` mode or you may need to call `reset_optimizer` before doing this operation if the `CachingOptimizer` is in `MANUAL` mode.

Comment: Could you help me to fix this errors, please?

Comment: Please post a reproducible example on our Discourse forum: https://discourse.julialang.org/c/domain/opt/13

Comment: No need. I've reproduced the bug.

Comment: I'll work on fixing this today: https://github.com/jump-dev/MultiObjectiveAlgorithms.jl/issues/75

Comment: Thank you, I've created a post on the forum. 
Link to access the post: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/multiobjectivealgorithms-jl-error-message/106876?u=igoresmelo